In atomic ionization via laser, the process is more efficient using a wavelength only slightly bluer than the threshold rather farther detuned. Why?
I have seen this phenomena referenced in several instances; however, I have been unsuccesful in finding a clear explanation for where this enhancement comes from or the term to describe this process.
I only have a hand wavey understanding that this stems from a greater density of states in the continuum in the frequency range directly above the ionization threshold. I would like to calculate the enhancement for given ionization process but do not know where to start.
